# how to setup qunit to ignore certain files?

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

I have the following setup in my qUnit.html file

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <Title> Batch Processing Tool Unit Test Report</Title>

    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="../../openui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                        "BatchProcessing": "../../",       
                        "test.unit": "./"
    }'
        data-sap-ui-frameOptions='deny'>
    </script>

    <script>
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.qunit.qunit-css");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.qunit");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.qunit.qunit-junit");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.qunit.qunit-coverage");

        QUnit.config.autostart = false;

        sap.ui.require(
            [
            "test/unit/controller/InputsView.controller",
            "test/unit/controller/TableView.controller",
            "test/unit/controller/DetailsView.controller"
            ],
            function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    QUnit.start();
                }, 5000);
            }
    );
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
        <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The problem is that when I go to look at my code coverage qUnit tries to cover every .js file in my project. How can I tell it to ignore certain files that I don't want to test. Is it possible to do it within the qUnit.html file or does it have to be strictly done through grunt?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer after looking around for a while. Here it is for anyone running into similar problems. 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/7ef32428dc7c4c048a8d7e8de0a556fb